# how to build an APK from ionic/react to install on my android device or publish on google play?

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, apk

how to build an APK from ionic/react to install on my android device or publish on google play ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the documentation for building [here](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/basics/building-your-app/).
So basically, you will need to follow the 3 steps mentioned. Thereafter in android studio, there is an option to build bundle/apk as shown here.

[image]

Thereafter its straightforward steps to build an apk :)